# EMT Conduit Strapping to a Narrow Joist

Tags: conduit

I going to run 1/2" EMT conduit on the bottom of a joist. The standard straps I have are too wide to get both nails/screws in. I would prefer to run the conduit down the center of the joist. I wouldn't be able to do this with a single nail/screw strap. I was thinking of using a thick metal tape with holes every inch or so in it. I have some holding up my gas line. Do they still make it? If so, what is it called? Or could I used plastic zip lock ties instead?

Comment: Some call it plumbers tape or strap, they do make single hole straps that would look better and only take 1 screw, I know looks under the house don't matter but I have had inspections where they wanted listed straps.

Comment: The bottom of a joist is not a particularly well guarded place to run EMT, though it is fairly tough.  Could you add a couple slight bends and have it ride along the side of the joist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called perforated strapping and it comes in steel or a plastic material. That would be OK to use.

Answer (score 4):

Try using a minerallac strap. I really not much for perforated strapping. See image although it is legal.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I hate these but they're what you asked for.

**EMT Drive Strap**

[image]

([Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-1-2-in-Electrical-Metallic-Tube-EMT-Drive-Straps-200-Pack-61401B/206126681?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal2_rr-_-203671390-_-206126681-_-N))

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this [Conduit Hanger](https://static.grainger.com/rp/s/is/image/Grainger/4RHZ4_AS01?$mdmain$)